# Ability to create records of custom objects?

Tags: custom-object, permissions

My profile is the Systems Administrator, but I am not able to create new records of a custom object that I made. I went to check permissions and it says that I have all the permissions to read/write/create.

Comment: Please explain how you are trying to create the records and what goes wrong.

Comment: So I am looking at my  custom object. At the top I have an edit and delete button, shouldn't I have a new button? I believe I have the proper permission set up so that I should be able to create new records of this object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the normal end-user UI, if you also [create a tab](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_custom_object_tabs.htm&language=en_US) to hold your custom object, when you navigate to the tab you will see a "New" button presented that you can create records with. The tab also lists any records already created. The detail view of an object doesn't display a "new" button but can display a "Clone" button to copy the object.

(If you are talking about the Setup UI, that is for defining the object name and fields not for creating new records.)